Angular reactive form local time to utc conversion
I have an Angular form that retrieves the time in UTC and converts it to local time based on the option selected from a dropdown menu.
The form acts like a real clock, keeping it in sync by incrementing the UTC time every second.
This solution works, but the issue is that I'm directly editing the UTC time. The selected time zone doesn't affect the UTC time; it only changes the displayed local time.
working example where the UTC is editited -
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-16-reactive-form-validation-rts11n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts
What I want is the following:

The local time should be editable in reactive form instead of UTC.
When I change the time zone, the form's local time should update based on the selected time zone.
The problem I'm facing is that after changing the time zone, the form's local time updates correctly. However, if I manually change the local time, the UTC is miscalculated and displays the wrong value, because formOnchanges takes the form value and calculates UTC based on that

